# will_paginate and facebook/facebooker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

I'm using will_paginate in a facebook application and when i click on 
the next button or a page number i get the url below. This is fine if 
everyone was using safari, but it breaks on ie and ff. That and people 
can't copy and paste the url to others. Anyone have any ideas how to 
fix this. 
http://apps.facebook.com/application/users/4785/votes.fbml?_method=GE...  URL TOO BIG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already discussed [here](http://groups.google.com/group/will_paginate/browse_thread/thread/88c2391f81da6b96). And solved.

Comment: I don't understand why is your question exactly the same as in the group I linked. Are you sure you ain't bot? Otherwise you could get the solution right there when you copied it.